arm qemu visualisation troubles
Want to make tiny os in arm architecture.
I have asm file:
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x20000
    bl kernel
hang:
    b hang

.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

and notmain.c
void kernel(void) {
    const char *msg = "Hello, ARM world!\n";
    unsigned int *vga_buffer = (unsigned int *)0xB8000; // VGA text mode buffer
    unsigned int color = 0x0F00; // White text on black background
    int i = 0;

    // Clear the screen
    for (i = 0; i < 80 * 25; ++i) {
        vga_buffer[i] = color | ' ';
    }

    // Print the message
    i = 0;
    while (*msg) {
        vga_buffer[i++] = color | *msg++;
    }

    while (1);
}

I want that in qemu emulator i see Hello, ARM world!, but i see:

How i can manage code for visualisation in qemu emulator?
Here my compilation stages:
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -march=armv5t strap.s -o strap.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -Wall -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -march=armv5t notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-ld strap.o notmain.o -T memmap -o notmain.elf
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.elf -O binary notmain.bin

And here qemu lauch (wihout emulator)
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel os.bin


Which Arm system did you select for emulation? (virt?) And which graphics output did you select? Is it VGA-compatible, at the same base address as in a PC?

I use qemu command qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M....

How did you compile your .asm and .c files? Show your build commands please.

@ImanAbdollahzadeh, added to post compilation stages

From where have you gotten the information that there's a PC VGA interface at that address? The physical version of this board has a VGA connector for display compatibility, but seems to use the colour LCD controller (CLCDC) in the ARM926EJ-S.

Your code assumes that there is a VGA display device at address 0xB8000. However you are running it on the versatilepb machine type, and that machine type does not have a VGA display device anywhere.
You need to write code that works with the graphical display that the machine you are running it on actually has. For the versatilepb that is a PL110/PL111 framebuffer:
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0161/e
This hardware does not have ASCII text-printing support -- it has a framebuffer that you draw pixels to.
If you want simply to print text on the versatilepb, then you're best off using the UART (serial port), rather than the graphical display. Otherwise you would need to implement your own handling of fonts and text drawing.
If you really want a VGA device then you would need to plug in a PCI VGA device via the QEMU command line. But then your OS would need at least enough PCI support to probe, enable and map the PCI BARs, because (unlike the x86 PC machine type) there is no BIOS code that runs before your OS to set up PCI for you.
